# 'Role size' error when provisioning Azure VM via Azure PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm trying to provision an Azure VM via the Azure PowerShell, like so: `New-AzureVMConfig -Name $vmName -InstanceSize "Medium" -ImageName $imageName | Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -Linux -LinuxUser $username -Password $password | New-AzureVM -ServiceName $serviceName -ReservedIPName $reservedIP -Location $location`

Naturally, all values for the variables have been set. When I execute the above command, I get the error: **New-AzureVM : BadRequest: Role size: Medium is not supported in a provisioned storage account.**

Alternatives I've used are Medium instead of "Medium", Small, Large and Standard_D1. Nothing works! What am I missing?

---

Note that the storage account I've set in my subscription (`Set-AzureSubscription`) uses premium storage. It was created via the command of sort `New-AzureStorageAccount -StorageAccountName "yourpremiumaccount" -Location "West US" -Type "Premium_LRS"` (documentation [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-premium-storage-preview-portal/)).

Needless to say, if I set it to an account using non-premium storage, the aforementioned `New-AzureVMConfig` command works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft, Premium storage VMs doesn't support the one you are using (Standard_Dx), you can check the full article [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-premium-storage/).

> Premium Storage Disks: Azure Premium Storage supports VM disks that can be attached to DS, DSv2 or GS series Azure VMs.

Try changing to one of the supported series like DS1 and it should work:

```
New-AzureVMConfig -Name $vmName -InstanceSize "Standard_DS1" -ImageName $imageName | Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -Linux -LinuxUser $username -Password $password | New-AzureVM -ServiceName $serviceName -ReservedIPName $reservedIP -Location $location
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work with all Instance sizes. For example, if one tries `InstanceSize: Standard_DS2`, it's going to work.

---

*I'll update this answer when I find the entire range of instance sizes it works with.*